# Django Wagtail responsive images

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Is it possible to create responive images that resize with the page in Wagtail?

Currently I have this:

```
{% for item in page.gallery_images.all %}
     <div class="pull-left img-responsive my-5">
         {% image item.image original %}
         <p>{{ item.caption }}</p>
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

but it does not become smaller in width and height when decrease the width of the page.

Answer (score 3):

This is outside of Wagtail's responsibility - responsive images are implemented in CSS, which is a detail Wagtail intentionally stays out of, to give you full flexibility to build and style your front-end pages however you like.

The `{% image %}` template tag will give you an `<img>` element at a fixed resolution of your choice; as long as that resolution is greater than the maximum size you intend to display it at (which should certainly be the case if you use `{% image item.image original %}`, although you could also consider something like `{% image item.image width-1000 %}` so that you're not wasting bandwidth serving up an oversized image, if the original was uploaded at an extremely high resolution), you can apply CSS styles as per [a guide like this one](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_responsive.asp) to provide responsive behaviour.

With your HTML structure given above, this might look like:

```
.img-responsive img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Oh awesome, I was forgetting the img tag in the styling element. Thank you again!

Comment: Is there a way to make a button and be able to change the href in wagtail admin? can't find any documentation.